# Update entity in EF with many to many navigational property

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, entity-framework-5

I have a question regarding EF and many to many relationship

I have a database with following tables: student, course, studentcourse (association table).
So due to association table I get a many to many relation.

This means that from student entity I can navigate to a list of all courses which are bound to him.

Imagine, i have following courses= 1 Programming, 2 English, 3 Analyse.

Now I get a new student and i want to add him to the database with 2 courses, I do it like that:

```
using(DBContext context = new DBContext())
{
    student s = new student();
    s.Name="John Doe";
    s.Courses = new List<course>(){new course() {Id=2, Name="English"}, new course() {Id=3, Name="Analyse"}};
    context.students.Add(s);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This will correctly add a new student and the relationship to the association table!
In my association table i will have following:
1 2
1 3

This is with combined PK.

Now this student suddenly decides to have instead of those 2 courses and another one, then i have to update it, but here I have an error!
I have following:

```
using(DBContext context = new DBContext())
{
    student s = context.students.Find(1);
    s.Courses = new List<Courses>().Add(new course(){Id=1, Name="Programming"});
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In this case i will get an error saying that the primary keys already exist, basically it will try to ADD all those courses again in the association table.

In my example it is more simple you can say you just give add 1 course and that one will be added and that is it, but i don't see the relationship there anymore, because the other 2 will not be delete although they should! If i change the name in that context and i save the change the name is updated but it doesn't try to add another instance of the student.

Imagine if there is a form with courses, and student goes there to modify only his name, and he resubmits the form, so basically the previous selected courses will be posted back to server and the application will try to process them, normally ok it can edit them again in the association table, or better if it compares and ignores if the courses the same ... but in my case it just try to add them again.

I hope i could explain clear, my problem, just to summarize my question is: how do I correctly update many to many referenced property?

Answer (score 0):

You should only add the Course to the Courses collection, do not replace the collection. Like this:

```
using(DBContext context = new DBContext())
{
    student s = context.students.Find(1);
    s.Courses.Add(new course(){Id=1, Name="Programming"});
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: you sure there is no other way?

Comment: this is the right way if you only want to add a new item to the collection.

Comment: but man, no, if i want to update student, i'm not doing first delete student and then re-add it, no i edit

Comment: I'm not talking about student, just `Courses` member of student.
In your code you have `s.Courses = s.Courses.Add(...)`. This way you are adding the entire collection. You should only have `s.Courses.Add(...)`

Comment: yes but it is being done automatically, next time they should be modified, because so if user insetad of those 2 courses chooses another one, they i have to delete manually and add one instead, but this is relationship, shouldn't it be done automatically

Comment: so basically if there is a list of courses and they are resubmitted everytime, so it is better if i delete all courses and add them over again ....

Comment: No, you should only add the new courses and delete the ones that are to be removed. The framework internally knows what to update on the database. If you only add a new course then the framework will only execute one insert on the database.

Comment: but how does he know when to update, if the framework doesn't know for example to update the same courses, because for example the id is the same but only update the id of courses

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44731/discussion-between-lbarreira-and-alnedru)